# View with two UIWebViews problems with height calculation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiwebview

I created a UIViewController having a view with two UIWebViews. My structure looks like this (I also use auto layout with [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)):

```
class MyIntViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

  private var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  private var contentView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    setupView()
  }


  private func setupView() {

    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
      make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
    }

    contentView = UIView()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
      make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView)
      make.width.equalTo(self.view.bounds.width)
    }

    // first webView

    let contentWebView1 = UIWebView()
    contentWebView1.scalesPageToFit = false
    contentWebView1.delegate = self
    contentWebView1.scrollView.bounces = false
    contentWebView1.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

    contentView.addSubview(contentWebView1)

    contentWebView1.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(contentView.snp_top)
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_left)
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.snp_right)
        make.height.equalTo(1)
    }

    // second webView

    let contentWebView2 = UIWebView()
    contentWebView2.scalesPageToFit = false
    contentWebView2.delegate = self
    contentWebView2.scrollView.bounces = false
    contentWebView2.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

    contentView.addSubview(contentWebView2)

    contentWebView2.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(contentWebView1.snp_bottom)
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_left)
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.snp_right)
        make.height.equalTo(1)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.snp_bottom)
    }

    // load content for contentWebView1 and contentWebView2

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
    let baseURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)!
    let myFileHtml: String = "HTWML for contentWebView1""
    let myFileHtmlPlusCss = MMCssHelper.appendCustomCSS(myFileHtml)
    contentWebView1.loadHTMLString(myFileHtmlPlusCss, baseURL: baseURL)

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
    let baseURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)!
    let myFileHtml: String = "HTWML for contentWebView2""
    let myFileHtmlPlusCss = MMCssHelper.appendCustomCSS(myFileHtml)
    contentWebView2.loadHTMLString(myFileHtmlPlusCss, baseURL: baseURL) 
  }

  // MARK: UIWebViewDelegate

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let webViewContentHeight: CGFloat = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

    println("webViewDidFinishLoad webViewContentHeight: \(webViewContentHeight)")

    webView.snp_updateConstraints { (make) -> Void in
      make.height.equalTo(webViewContentHeight)
    }
  }

}
```

When I have only one UIWebView on the page everything works fine the content of the UIWebView is calculated correctly in `webViewDidFinishLoad`. The problem occurs with two UIViewViews as shown above. The console output is this:

```
webViewDidFinishLoad webViewContentHeight: 1.0
webViewDidFinishLoad webViewContentHeight: 17.0
```

You can see that one webViewContentHeight is calculated correct while the other seems to be not calculated at all.

**How do I get the height of a `UIWebView` calculated correctly when there are more than one UIWebViews on the page?**